# Unable to login via ssh to remote Ubuntu machine - connection refused

Tags: ssh, login

I have a very recently installed Ubuntu box and the only change I have made is change the hostname to mail  and hosts file now says:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1       mail
```

Anyway if I attempt to login via ssh (this is from a Windows 7 box) I login like this:

```
C:\Users\angus>ssh -vv acomber@192.168.0.52
OpenSSH_5.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.52 [192.168.0.52] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.52 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.52 port 22: Connection refused
```

So doesn't work.

I can ping the host ok.

Here is my /var/log/auth.log file:

```
acomber@mail:~$ tail -f /var/log/auth.log
Jul 12 11:52:56 mail compiz: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so):  /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jul 12 11:52:56 mail compiz: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Jul 12 11:52:56 mail compiz: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "acomber"
Jul 12 11:58:40 mail compiz: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Jul 12 12:13:44 mail compiz: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jul 12 12:13:44 mail compiz: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Jul 12 12:13:44 mail compiz: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "acomber"
Jul 12 12:14:04 mail compiz: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Jul 12 12:17:01 mail CRON[3639]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 12 12:17:01 mail CRON[3639]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

What does this mean:
pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "acomber"

Do I have to specify password on ssh login?

I am new to Ubuntu and so I expect it is something pretty basic that is wrong.

What should I be checking from here?

UPDATE

Thanks for the tip saiarcot895.  If I attempt to login locally by ssh -vv acomber@localhost I get:

```
acomber@mail:/etc/ssh$ ssh -vv acomber@localhost
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

But I can login ok using Xterm.  so I assumed on the localhost I could connect ok.

That's confusing me because /etc/ssh/ssh_config is for the ssh client configuration?  I thought it must be a problem in ssh server config?  By the way, where do I look for ssh server config?

MORE INFO

```
acomber@mail:/etc/ssh$ ps aux | grep ssh
acomber   2095  0.0  0.0  10616   316 ?        Ss   12:47   0:00 ssh-agent -s
acomber   2978  0.0  0.0  15948   916 pts/1    S+   13:08   0:00 grep --color=auto ssh


acomber@mail:/etc/ssh$ netstat -l | grep ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13527    /tmp/ssh-joANPbVpPNT3/agent.2094
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14292    /run/user/1000/keyring-M9AniG/ssh
```

How does XTerm work then?  I assumed it must connect to an ssh server???

Comment: Note the times on the messages you referenced. That message was at least 4 minutes ago, and `compiz` is related to drawing the graphics. Also, on an SSH login, you will need to authenticate yourself in some way (either a publickey or a password), but it will prompt you for the password, rather than completely fail. This seems to be a connection issue. Have you tried SSH'ing locally on the remote machine (e.g. `ssh 127.0.0.1` on the remote machine)?

Comment: Your session ends before the connection is even established, i.e. before logins and passwords are sent. Is your ssh server running? You can find that out by doing `ps aux | grep sshd` and `netstat -l | grep ssh`.

Comment: I found this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1309535)

Comment: Your ssh server is not running. `ssh-agent` is running but it is not a server. Furthermore, there is no process connected to the ssh port 22. Start a server process with `/usr/sbin/sshd -D`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to have a running `ssh` server. If this is a fresh installation, it is likely that none is installed.

1. Install an `ssh` server.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssh-server
   ```
2. If the server is already installed, start it:

   ```
   sudo service ssh start
   ```

You should now be able to log in normally.