# SSH: Network problem with login

Tags: networking, ssh, login

Two days ago I logged on server via ssh without any problems. Today I tried to do so 3 times with wrong login (simple mistake), it said there was a login error, so I checked and put in correct login. After that it just stopped and returned Connection timed out. Full output with -vvv argument:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 194.29.169.1 [194.29.169.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 194.29.169.1 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 194.29.169.1 port 22: Connection timed out
```

What's more - I tried to go back to this wrong login but now it gave the same result as the correct one.

After hours of searching the solution (firewall etc.) I tried to set up the connection on Windows (Putty) as well as on Windows on different computer but the result was the same. It indicated that it wasn't a platform issue but the connection couldn't be set up because of network. As I thought - after connecting to my mobile hotspot I could set up ssh connection without any troubles. I asked a friend to log on his platform and network and he succeeded as well.

Do you have any idea what could have caused that?

Comment: What exactly indicated "that it wasn't a platform issue but the connection couldn't be set up because of network"? can you successfully `ping 194.29.169.1 22`? Does `telnet 194.29.169.1 22` indicate a listening SSH server? (you can exit the latter using Ctrl-] then Ctrl-D)

Comment: The fact that I tried this on 2 different computers and 2 operating systems. Yes, I can ping it but telnet returned `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`

Comment: My best guess is that the remote server has some kind of additional access control such as `fail2ban` that has (at least temporarily) banned your IP address from connecting

Comment: Maybe stupid question but your ouput looks exactly the same as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/496805/423684) .. so are you sure the ssh server is running on the server?

Comment: @steeldriver you were right, setting up new 3 hours session on server went without any problems :) thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

@[steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) hit the nail on the head: this is a [fail2ban](/questions/tagged/fail2ban) (or similar) tool blocking (temporarily) your IP address.

It may be worth [whitelisting](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Whitelist) your IP (though, if you're on a non-static connection method (eg from a home cable modem), this won't be effective; or if your machine is compromised, it could auto-login to remote devices and run nefarious content thereon):

> Whitelisting is setup in the `jail.conf` file using a space separated list.

```
[DEFAULT]
# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host. Fail2ban will not                          
# ban a host which matches an address in this list. Several addresses can be                             
# defined using space separator.
```

> or

```
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.0/24 8.8.8.8 
# This will ignore connection coming from common private networks.
# Note that local connections can come from other than just 127.0.0.1, so
# this needs CIDR range too.
ignoreip = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16
```

You might also consider increasing the number of bad tries and/or cutting the length of the ban - see the [fail2ban](http://fail2ban.org) [jail options](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Jail_Options) documentation.